# php if isset in SQL string

Tags: php, sql

(Duplicate marked) - has nothing to do with this...
I am outputting an array of user data in to a HTML table (`<tr>`), and I am trying to impliment a search field, where you can search for a specific IP (`WHERE IP LIKE ip`). But I am having trouble adding this, as I only want it to search for `WHERE IP LIKE ip` when a search has actually been made. Right now, this iss how I tried to do it:

```
$users = $db->get ("user_data" . if(isset($_GET['ip'])) { echo "WHERE IP LIKE '$_GET[ip]'"} . "ORDER BY date DESC, time DESC LIMIT 10");
```

This gives me the error, "Parse error: syntax error, unexpected T_IF ... "

I have no clue what would be wrong with the code, other than it doesn't like me putting "if" where I put it... I am wanting to make a search for every single value (7), but so far it isn't going too well...

In the long run, I am working towards a result like this; http://namelessmc.com/members

Thank you in advance :)

Comment: Is your problem resolved ?

Comment: @SonuR Yes, with a completely other solution though.

Answer (score 0):

Try like this.

```
$ip = "";
if(isset($_GET['ip']) && $_GET['ip']) { 
$ip = " WHERE IP LIKE '%".$_GET['ip']."%' ";
}
 $users = $db->get ("user_data" . $ip. " ORDER BY date DESC, time DESC LIMIT 10");
```

isset check for existence and you should also check for its value if you are sending variable ip in each request.

Comment: This actually makes the table appear, but the search doesn't work, `$ip` seems to be empty nomatter what (even if I put it within `} else {`. It also isn't really optimal having an empty variable, as it gives errors.

Comment: have changed $_GET[ip] to $_GET['ip'] in my ans, check now

Comment: Didn't change a thing. Search still doesn't work - this answer isn't optimal, leaving a variable empty is a bad idea. I am sure there is another, completely clean solution for this.

Comment: Also make sure value of $_GET['ip'] is coming properly.

Comment: It just doesn't work.

Comment: may be LIKE will work with "%" Symbol , have edited my ans again.

Comment: that's not the problem.